# What are the drawbacks to staying in hybrid form constantly?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have a character who has natural Lycanthrope. Aside from the obvious drawbacks of scaring people and possibly being attacked, are there any other drawbacks to staying in hybrid form constantly? If there are any drawbacks what would be the best way to avoid them?

Wanting to stay in hybrid form is purely for RP reasons and not for mechanical benefit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## There Are No Mechanical Drawbacks

I've played a [lycanthrope](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lycanthrope)<sup>1</sup> in *Pathfinder* and were it not for the fact that the campaign was lycanthrope-unfriendly<sup>2</sup>, my half-orc werewolf inquisitor<sup>3</sup> would've totally stayed in hybrid form all the time.

So what if the bad guys *know* that silver overcomes your damage reduction? You *still* have damage reduction, and most of the monsters aren't eating you with silver teeth.

One thing, though. A *natural* lycanthrope (in other words, the *best* kind) can inflict the curse of lycanthropy with its bite attack; the DM may rule that when a creature you kill whom you've bitten is the subject of the spell [*raise dead*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/raise-dead) et. al. that the creature is brought back from the dead as an afflicted lycanthrope if the creature qualifies and fails its saving throw. (According to *raise dead*, "curses are not undone" by being brought back from the dead.)

---

1. Unintentionally. My character got bit and failed the saving throw.
2. The campaign was set in *Magic: The Gathering*'s [Innistrad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innistrad) but used *Pathfinder* rules.
3. He was as cool as he sounds.